# My subscription can't seem to complete correctly on the component, even though the service is called correctly

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, observable, subject

I'm not sure if I understand why my subscription is not completing properly.

Here's the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FormService {
    private $formSubject: Subject<FormGroup> = new Subject<FormGroup>();
    private testForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
       foo: [null, Validators.required],
       bar: [null, Validators.required]
    });

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.$formSubject.next(this.testForm)
  }

  getForm(): Observable<FormGroup> {
    console.log('It gets to the getForm in the service...')
    return this.$formSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

And here's the component that should subscribe to the form:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { FormService } from './app-form.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  private formSub: Subscription;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.formSub = this.formService.getForm()
      .subscribe(
        (form: FormGroup) => {
          console.log(form);
          this.form = form;
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.formSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I created a Stackblitz replicating the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trd3iq

For a standard behavior, I'm expecting the variable `isLoading` to be set to false and for the dom to reflect it (with 'done!').

I'm also expecting to get `console.log` in the component.ts to print.

EDIT: I just changed the Subject for a BehaviorSubject and it works... I'm not sure to understand fully why though it wouldn't work as previously presented.

Comment: EDIT: I just changed the Subject for a BehaviorSubject and it works... I'm not sure to understand fully why though it wouldn't work as previously presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service constructor would be called much before your `component` `ngOnInit` is called, this means you are you are subscribing the subject after its emisssion.

Changing the Subject with a BehaviorSubject and not emitting in constructor but initializing with `testForm` should do the trick.

```
private $formSubject: Subject<FormGroup> = new BehaviorSubject<FormGroup>(this.testForm);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adjdzq?file=src/app/app-form.service.ts)

Comment: Hey Ashish! Thanks for the answer! It shed some lights on why this was happening! all the best!